# Atomic move and many processes running it at the same time

Tags: java, nio

In my application I have scheduled task that monitor a directory for files with certain extension. Those files are further processed. There can be a multiple processes executing this app and to prevent multiple instances from processing the same file I change its extension so its not listed another time using `Files.move` with `ATOMIC_MOVE` option. There is a chance that more than one instance of app try to execute this method at the same time though - my question is: what happens then? Should I expect some exceptions being thrown?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to count on a correct behavior: first one "wins", second one gets `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`, so you catch that particular exception and ignore the file.

```
try {
    Files.move(previousPath, renamedPath, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
}
catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
    /* Another process has already processed that file. Ignore and move on. */
}
catch (IOException e) {
    /* Must handle that one: something else has failed */
}
```

I've verified on Linux and macOS with a program that lists a directory with some files, and renames them all with a random UUID, and running several instances of that program on the same directory for a while. I got many `NoSuchFileException` but nothing else.

I would be quite confident with this on a local filesystem. However, if you're using that on a networked filesystem (NFS...), all bets are off.

Comment: `NoSuchFileException` would indicate that this file had already been moved before `Files#move` was invoked by another process - what if the method was being invoked by both processes at the same time though?

Comment: Mu understanding is that the method guarantees you'll get a `NoSuchFileException` all the same: whatever the underlying platform is, it tries to move the file atomically, and in the situation you describe, the file would simply not be there: it would yield an error that will translate to `NoSuchFileException` in the java layer

Comment: In the case of unix platforms, see source for [`UnixException.translateToIOException()`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/jdk8u60-b10/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixException.java#L77-L92) where the underlying platform-specific error is translated to IOException. If the move is atomic, second call gets `ENOENT` which is translated to `NoSuchFileException`.

Comment: Important precision (added a mention in answer): I was assuming local filesystem... With NFS it would get wildly more complicated :-/

Comment: Your assumption was good - it'll be used on local filesystem but that's a valid point you've made here.